# Very specific Java generics issue - how to return the same type that was passed into a method?

Tags: java, generics, types

In my game engine I have a List of `Entity` objects, of which there are many subclasses (e.g. `Player`, `Cube`, `Camera`, etc). I would like to have a method where I pass a `Class` object in, and end up with a List of the same class - e.g. I'd like to say something like this:

```
List<Box> boxes = getEntities(Box.class);
```

So far I have this:

```
public List<Entity> getEntities(Class<? extends Entity> t) {
    ArrayList<Entity> list = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Entity e : entities) {
        if (e.getClass() == t) {
            list.add(e);
        }
    }

    return Collections.unmodifiableList(list);
}
```

But of course that returns a List of `Entity`s, which means each instance in the List must be cast to the `Box` class. Is there a way to do this properly in Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend the following, which builds on the existing answers, but avoids `@SuppressWarnings`, etc:

```
public <E extends Entity> List<E> getEntities(Class<E> type) {

    List<E> list = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Entity e : entities) {
        if (type.isInstance(e)) {
            list.add(type.cast(e));
        }
    }

    return Collections.unmodifiableList(list);
}
```

Or if you're using [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com):

```
public <E extends Entity> ImmutableList<E> getEntities(Class<E> type) {
    return ImmutableList.copyOf(Iterables.filter(entities, type));
}
```

Comment: That's amazing! I did write something similar, but with E extends Entity in each pair of <>'s - it didn't like that! So you just put the generic types after the access modifier then?

Comment: @Javawag Exactly - you only need to specify the upper bound (`extends Entity`) when declaring the type parameter for the method (after modifiers and before return type). Once it's declared you can just refer to it like any other type.

Answer (score 1):

Make your method generic, with an upper bound.

```
public <T extends Entity> List<T> getEntities(Class<T> t) {
```

Then replace `Entity` with `T` in the next line of your code.

```
ArrayList<T> list = new ArrayList<>;
```

**EDIT**

As @arshajii pointed out in a comment, `e` will need to be casted to `T`, to match the type of `list`.

Comment: You'll need the cast `(T) e` in the `for`-loop, and you might want an `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` to go along with it.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline What would be the difference, in this case (aside from the warning)?

Comment: Or are you suggesting `t.cast` specifically to avoid the warning?

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
public static List<? extends Entity> getEntities(Class<? extends Entity> t) {
    ArrayList<Entity> list = new ArrayList<Entity>();

    for (Entity e : entities) {
        if (e.getClass() == t) {
            list.add(e);
        }
    }

    return Collections.unmodifiableList(list);
}
```

and then you can call:

```
List<Box> boxes = (List<Box>) getEntities(Box.class);
```

Now you don't have to cast every single object of the list.